# Android HTTP errors when using POST with Appcelerator

Tags: android, http, post, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator to build an app for both iOS and Android.

Part of the app requires HTTP POSTs to an API.

This works great on iOS, but fails on Android, giving me this error in the process...

```
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Acceptable
```

I understand there may be a few differences in how Android handles these calls, but I'm not exactly sure what I need to change in order for them to work.

Here is one of the calls I'm making.

Any pointers on what i could be doing wrong?

```
function doRegister() {
            // check to see if we already have a username saved
            if (!Ti.App.Properties.getString('userEmail')) {

                var userEmailfromBox = Ti.App.Properties.getString('userEmailfromBox');
                var HashedEmail = Ti.Utils.sha256(userEmailfromBox);

                var registerData = {
                    "account": {
                        "name": userEmailfromBox,
                        "mail": userEmailfromBox,
                        "pass": HashedEmail,
                        "field_user_type": {
                            "und": "xxxxx"
                        }
                    }
                };

                var registration = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                    onload: function() {
                        // handle the response
                        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);

                        // need to save this email so we don't keep registering the user
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('userEmail', userEmailfromBox);

                        // then we need to load the next step
                        doLogin();
                    },
                    onerror : function(e) {
                         Ti.API.info('Registering: ' + e.error);
                         //alert('error');

                         // then we need to load the next step
                        //doLogin();
                     }
                });
                registration.open('POST', 'https://www.myurlredacted.com');

                // change the loading message
                //loaderWheel.message = 'Creating User';
                loaderWheel.message = 'Uploading Your Photos';
                // show the indicator
                loaderWheel.show();

                // set the header for the correct JSON format
                registration.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                // send the data to the server
                registration.send(JSON.stringify(registerData));

            } else {
                // user is already registered, so skip them onto the next step
                Ti.API.info('user already registered');
                // then we need to load the next step
                doLogin();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following code based on yours:

```
var url = "http://requestb.in/1iuahxb1";

var registerData = {
    "account": {
        "name": 'userEmailfromBox',
        "mail": 'userEmailfromBox',
        "pass": 'HashedEmail',
        "field_user_type": {
            "und": "xxxxx"
        }
    }
};

var registration = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function () {
        // handle the response
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
    },
    onerror: function (e) {
        Ti.API.info('Registering: ' + e.error);
    }
});

registration.open('POST', url);

// set the header for the correct JSON format
registration.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
// send the data to the server
registration.send(JSON.stringify(registerData));
```

It runs without errors and the requestb.in recieves the post:

http://requestb.in/1iuahxb1?inspect

Comment: Do you think it could be something server side then that is causing the errors? It's hitting an API created in Drupal.

Comment: I guess. Since the error says there's an exception in the response it looks like Drupal is returning something it can't handle. You'll have to intercept what Drupal is sending to debug that.